# Error creating driver 'Hadoop / Apache Drill' instance in DBeaver 5.3.4

Tags: jdbc, apache-drill, dbeaver

I am getting below error while trying to connect to a drillbit instance running on my RHEL box from DBeaver installed on my windows machine .

Can't create driver instance
Error creating driver 'Hadoop / Apache Drill' instance.
Most likely required jar files are missing.
You should configure jars in driver settings.

Reason: can't load driver class 'org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver'
Error creating driver 'Hadoop / Apache Drill' instance.
Most likely required jar files are missing.
You should configure jars in driver settings.

Reason: can't load driver class 'org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver'
org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver

I had previous downloaded file drill-jdbc-all-1.17.0.jar and in Edit Driver setting in libraries tab added this file and it had worked for me. I had also kept drill-jdbc-all-1.17.0.jar inside installation path of DBeaver DBeaver/plugins directory. Strangely this is not working now.

Answer (score 2):

I had Clicked "Add File" in Edit Connection ( Libraries tab ) to add single jar file drill-jdbc-all-.jar. Depending on situation people can "Add Folder" to add folder with Java classes/resources and "Add Artifact" to add Maven artifact (see below).

After I added jar files I was able to find all JDBC driver classes which present in these jars. Just click on the "Find Class" button and DBeaver will show all of them. In most cases there is just one driver class in the driver. Then i clicked ok and Entered port number on the other page and tried to reconnect and was able to connect fine. Also this link could be helpful.

https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Database-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add...

If you're having difficulty connecting, try the following connection string with your hostname:

```
jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost
```

[image]